# Make clipboard content verifier detect images and another things permitted in the clipboard in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a C # application called TextEditor that is used to write text and paste as much as possible in a RichTextBox1, that is, a basic text editor system with several functions, but my code only detects text and blocks the option to paste with images and everything else (except text), paste images with CTRL + V, I would think that a solution would be something similar to the following, although I do not know how to do it with a clipboard:

```
if (water = "")
{
no = true;
yes = false;
}
else {
no = false;
yes = true;
}
```

This was what I tried and only enabled it with text, and I want it to be always enabled except when there is nothing, and I include images.
I have a button to paste.

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

I expected that it detects everything, but only detects text, it is only for text, but I do not know how to do it for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Thanks to emmademontford, i find the solution in he's/she's code

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;

if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
pegarToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to place a Key Down event in RichTextBox. You can do this by going in to the designer > click your RichTextBox > events > OnKeyDown. Try this code:

```
  private void RtbDocKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
       {
       if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
       {
           DataFormats.Format df = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
           StringCollection strcollect = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();

           Image image= Image.FromFile(strcollect[0]);
           Clipboard.Clear();
           Clipboard.SetImage(image);
           if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
           {
               rtbBody.Paste(df);
               e.Handled = true;
               Clipboard.Clear();
           }
       }
```

Comment: I have a button than says paste, i want to control this button, not ctrl + v.

Comment: Okay so on your button_click event, use the code above starting at:

           DataFormats.Format df = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);